# Button press effect not working in css

Tags: javascript, css

I want to have this button pressed effect in css. I mean for example lets say I press a button then I want to change its css so that it looks pressed. Here is something that I tried. But it's not working. I used example from a site. But the button's size gets smaller and it looks different. Here is the link for the code     http://jsfiddle.net/goku/GdD34/

```
.pressed{ 
  position:relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: #fqq;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
input.happy {
    background-image: url(/img/happy.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
}


$('.happy').click(function() {
    alert('hello');
    $('.happy').attr('class','pressed');
});

<input type="button" class="happy">
```

Comment: In your fiddle, you have put the selector wrong, you forgot the dot (.)

Answer (score 0):

Just used the :active pseudo-class.

```
input.happy:active { /* Your style */ }
```

Answer (score 0):

You had some syntax errors.

Best event for this isn't `.click()`, its `.mousedown()`;

**When you click the Button without Releasing:**

```
$('.happy').mousedown(function() {
        $('.happy').attr('class','pressed');
    });
```

I believe now it's working : http://jsfiddle.net/HKZ7M/

Then when you release the mouse, give it back the old class.

**When you Click the Button then Release it**

```
    $('.happy').mousedown(function() {
        $('.happy').attr('class','pressed');

        $('.pressed').mouseup(function() {
            $('.pressed').attr('class','happy');
        });
    });
```

It's working : http://jsfiddle.net/Xx2Gn/

**Important Note:** The `.pressed` button is smaller than the `.happy` button, when you release the mouse you have to make sure that the pointer will be above the new `.pressed` button, that's why [you must make them the same size](http://jsfiddle.net/VyDXf/).

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you're replacing the class and not adding a new one. you should use :

```
$('.happy').addClass('pressed');
```

Instead of :

```
$('.happy').attr('class','pressed');
```

Because when u do that you remove all the css you previously applied to it. Your other option it to add the width/height or any other css to the `pressed` class.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you change the order of your CSS, the and the JS to:

```
<style>
input.happy {
    background-image: url(/img/happy.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: none;
    width: 64px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius:8px;
    -moz-border-radius:8px;
    -webkit-border-radius:8px;
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px #000;
}
input.happy.pressed{ 
  position:relative;
  top: 3px;
  color: #fqq;
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".happy").click(function(){
        $(this).addClass("pressed");
    });
});
</script>
<input type="button" class="happy">
```

Note, the "$(function(){" bit says "do this after page load". "addClass" will add the class to the list of classes for an element, but the event must be assigned after the DOM has loaded.

Also, you must use '$(this)' instead of '$(".happy")' inside the click function as to only apply the style to the button that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code (fiddle):

- I guess you want to use a javascript framework (like jQuery), you did not select one in the fiddle.
- You have a typo in the fiddle, inside the function it says `$('happy')` so no element will be found.
- You remove the class "happy" within the javascript and replace it with pressed. Maybe you want to apply both `$('.happy').attr('class', 'happy pressed');` But then for change `.pressed` to `input.pressed` and move below `.happy`
- Perhaps you don't want **all** buttons to change, use use `$(this).attr(...)` inside the function